# Empty output file

Tags: python

I have the following which, no matter what I have in the input file, gives me an empty file in the end, but I have no idea why, so I'd like to ask for your help if possible, thank you.

```
    import re
    import sys
    import os

    if len(sys.argv) > 1 :
         inf = sys.argv[1]
         if os.path.isfile(inf) :
             pass
         else :
              print "Nincs ilyen file!"
              sys.exit(0)
    else :
        print "Nincs argumentum!"

    infile = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
    outfile = open("out.txt","w")

    for t in infile :
         lista = t.split(";;;")
    for i in range(0,len(lista)):
         if lista[i] == "begin" :
              outfile.write("def "+lista[i-1]+"\n")
         elif lista[i] == "end;" :
              outfile.write(lista[i+1]+"\n")
         else :
              outfile.write("    "+lista[i]+"\n")
```

EDIT:

I have tried even just having it write something into the output file, but it still didn't do anything.

Comment: what does `lista` contains after reading `infile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the whole file before checking any of the lines. Therefore `lista` represents the *last* line of the file. Probably you want the second `for` loop indented *inside* the first one so it runs for each line of the file, not just the last.

Also, please, no `for i in range(...)` to access lists, it makes the Baby Jesus cry. `for item in lista` would be much better, then you just test `if item == "begin"` and so on.

Comment: He needs the list index because he needs `lista[i-1]` and `lista[i-1]`.  This calls for `enumerate`.

Comment: Or just the good old-fashioned "keep the last value around" technique.

Comment: True except he needs `lista[i+1]` as well (which was supposed to be in my first comment, but I accidentally typed `-` for both.  You can't keep a value around that you haven't seen yet.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to close your output file when you're done writing to it. Otherwise your write statements won't be saved.

At the end of your script add:

```
outfile.close()
```

Best practice is also to close any files you're reading from as well.

Comment: Because of that the `with` construct is better than it seems to be. (Yes, it is still unusual but...) My +1